# Horizontally scaling an application that shares input between servers

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, scalability, latency

I'm building an application that accepts input over a websocket that has to be shared back to other clients that may be connected to other frontend servers.

For simplicity imagine a multiuser multiroom chat application. Getting the input routed to the correct connection isn't a problem it's the messaging between the servers and being able to scale that and keep the latency of the messages in check.

Right now I have a broker process that each frontend connects to, they then subscribe to a queue for anything its connections might need to know about. This is being done to cut out receiving messages from the broker that will never be used by a frontend. However, I still get about 75% to 85% of the messages being sent back to each frontend from the broker.

On the trip in I'm doing message validation, parsing and any other business logic work. On the trip out I'm looping over the local array for the subscription and sending the message to each subscribed connection.

An example: If I'm getting 10 messages in across 11 frontend servers that's something around (110 total messages - 10 messages handled locally and not sent back by the broker) * 0.75 optimistic subscription level = 75 messages being sent back to each server to handle. So we have 10 local + 75 broker = 85 messages being processed for that slice of time by each server.

Now I wouldn't have 11 frontend servers for 100 msg/sec maybe two but the messages being sent back to each frontend server by the broker process would appear to explode the more messages I receive across additional frontend servers.

The broker process is a small node.js application that talks to RabbitMQ and PostgreSQL. The frontend servers are also node.js applications.

What can I do or should I be doing differently to keep latency low during periods of high volume?

Update to reply user comment: While I expect a lot of overlap between the queues the connections will cause their frontend server to subscribe to I don't expect it to be 100% for each server. Worst case is every frontend server has to subscribe to every queue on the broker thus getting 100% of the messages back from the broker. Optimistically, only about 75% of the messages will really need to be sent back to any specific frontend server.

Second Update for itaifrenkel: It is possible that a message sent by two users might be returned in different orders. It would only be acceptable if the latency was very low and it only happens with messages send very close to each other. If it was happening with messages seconds apart then I'd say we have an issue with latency and scale.

There is a case where we would need to display a history but I left that out because I felt it was out of the scope of the question.

Comment: You say overhead is 75% regardless of message being used or not. Then why do you use such optimistic subscription. Should it not be strictly on use basis. How do you decide to subscribe or not.

Comment: If a chat room is crowded, Is it valid that two users in the same chat room see two messages in different order?

Comment: When a user logs-in to the chat room, would there be any benefit in providing historical messages before the user logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

A message queue solution sounds like the correct option. And as you suggest in the title, to scale that, you need to go horizontal.

I haven't worked with RabbitMQ, so I can't blow you away with detail, but horizontal scaling means a cluster, so http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html might have enough to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that each user connects only to one chat room at any single time. That would mean one websocket connection = one chat room. So you would write an additional node.js reverse proxy that would forward each user connection to the "front-end" node.js process that is most likely already listening for events of that chat room (chat room affinity using consistent hashing based on the chatroom id). This routing algorithm needs to be best-effort to improve network utilization, it doesn't need to be perfect.

Now let's allow each user to be in more than one chat room. You would then need to improve the reverse proxy to connect to more than one "front-end" server and multiplex the results back to the user.

This design would provide horizontal scalability on the expense of network latency.

Note: Ofcourse the new reverse proxy is now the front-end server, but when I mention "front-end" I refer to the servers as you described them in the question.